# MDBDataTable: how to add a button in a column when data is a json file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbootstrap

I'm having the MDBTable that looks like this:

```
//import things
const DatatablePage = () => {
    const data = {
        columns: [
            {
                label: 'Stock Code',
                field: 'StockCode',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 150
            },
            {
                label: 'Item Description',
                field: 'ItemDes',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 270
            },
            {
                label: 'Unit Price',
                field: 'UnitPrice',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 200,
            },
            {
                label: 'In Stock',
                field: 'QUANTITY',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 100
            },
            {
                label: 'Add to Cart',
                field: null,
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 150
            }
        ],
        rows: table
    };

    return (
        <MDBDataTable
            striped
            bordered
            small
            hover
            theadColor="blue lighten-1"
            data={data}
            btn
            className="blueTable"
        />
    );
}

export default DatatablePage;
```

The JSON file looks like this (one sample for example):

```
[{"StockCode":"72800B","ItemDes":"4 PURPLE FLOCK DINNER CANDLES","UnitPrice":2.55,"QUANTITY":17},..]
```

I want the column "Add To Cart" to have a MDBButton. How do I do that?
I searched high and low and I found that I had to insert that MDBButton to the JSON file, per object. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set define the button directly where you prepare your table rows data:

```
const table = [
    {..., 
        addBtn : <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.addToCart()}>Add</button>
    }
]
```

And in the columns just define the **field** property with the same name **addBtn**:

```
 {
     label: 'Add to Cart',
     field: addBtn
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **columns** object, you can add an action button like this

```
{
   label: "Action",
   field: "action",
}
```

And inside **rows** object, you add a link like below

```
{
   action: <Link to='/view' className='btn btn-success btn-sm'>View</Link>
}
```